# Orca screen reader not working after changing settings

Tags: 16.04, orca

Earlier Orca was giving speech output but after I gave the command `orca --text-setup` on terminal and pressed '`y`' for all the options Orca is not giving any audio.

How can I get Orca to work?

Comment: I recommend you to run `orca --text-setup` again, but **read** what's on the screen before pressing *Yes* or *No*. You can do it through the GUI configuration dialog with `orca --gui-setup`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by doing the setup through the RUN window ie press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Seems it doesn't get to the language setting if try setup using terminal so it runs in the background not doing anything.

So reboot your computer & press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and a RUN box will appear.

Type: `orca -t` and make sure to tick the **Run in terminal** box before clicking the <kbd>Run</kbd> button.

A menu will appear. I chose **4. espeak**  as I was able to get espeak to work independently in terminal on my system. I checked by typing in a new terminal:  `espeak "hello"` & it spoke to me, wonderful!

Next it came up with a language selection choice. This menu was missing if I tried setup through terminal. Choose your language. I chose **Yes** for all the subsequent questions except **Braile** which I set to **No**. Also I chose option 2. for Laptop.

Press enter at the end, terminal may or may not close but it seems not to matter either way.

You may need to turn on screen reader:

**Applications > System Tools > System Settings > Universal Access > follow your nose**